# Mono.then() not executing when in tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-2

I'm trying to test the following code using integration tests:

```java
return ((Mono<Object>) joinPoint.proceed()).then(provider.getAuthor().flatMap((author) -> {
            Arrays.stream(joinPoint.getArgs())
                    .forEach(arg -> javers.commitShallowDeleteById(author, InstanceIdDTO.instanceId(arg.toString(), deletedEntity)));
            return Mono.empty();
        }));
```

`jointPoint.proceeed()` Always returns a `Mono<Void>` so that's why i'm using `then()`.

When running the app in debug mode if i place a breakpoint inside the flatmap i can see it passes through there, however if i run it in a `@SpringBootTest` in no longer passes inside the flatmap.

Test configuration:

```java
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Provider:
`when(authorProvider.getAuthor()).thenReturn(Mono.just("Author"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maybe `provider.getAuthor()` returns no value (a `Mono.empty()`) when you run your test?

   A `flatMap` needs a value to operate on. If there is no value, it won't be called. You can add a `doOnComplete()` call and see whether it is triggered when the sequence completes.

   Are the web application and the test running with the same data?
2. "*Nothing happens until you subscribe*"

   You can add a `doOnSubscribe()` call and see whether it is triggered and when, when running the test.

Comment: Just edited the question to provide details regarding the author.
`getAuthor()` is mocked and always returns `Mono.just("Author")`

Comment: Regarding 2, you were correct.
I was calling the method that triggered the aspect but i was ignoring the return value, and so there was no subscription.
Been banging my head on this for some hours now, thank you.

Comment: Will mark this answer as correct since it pointed out the possible issues causing this.